# How to use Dependency Injection with Spring Boot Unit Testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

Is it possible to use dependency injection with unit tests using Spring Boot? For integration testing `@SpringBootTest` start the whole application context and container services. But is it possible to enable dependency injection functionality at unit test granularity?

Here's the example code

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private MyRepository repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private MyService service; // <-- this is null
    
    @Test
    void getData() {
        MyEntity e1 = new MyEntity("hello");
        MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity("world");
        
        Mockito.when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
        
        List<String> data = service.getData();
        
        assertEquals(2, data.size());
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    
    private final MyRepository repo; // <-- this is null
    
    public MyService(MyRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    public List<String> getData() {
        return repo.findAll().stream()
                .map(MyEntity::getData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Or should I just manage the SUT (service class) as POJO and manually inject the mocked dependencies? I want to keep tests fast but minimize boilerplate code.

Comment: If you want a unit test don't use dependency injection if you want an integration test or system test use injection. Here it doesn't add anything but complexity and slow tests. Just replace `@Autowired` with `@InjectMocks` and `@MockBean` with `@Mock` and use the proper mockito runner instead of the spring extension. Or just manually create the mock and instance of your service (even faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M.Deinum mentioned in the comments, unit tests shouldn't use dependency injection. Mock `MyRepository` and inject `MyService` using Mockito (and Junit5):

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;

    @Mock
    private MyRepository repo;

    @Test
    void getData() {
        MyEntity e1 = new MyEntity("hello");
        MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity("world");

        Mockito.when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));

        List<String> data = service.getData();

        assertEquals(2, data.size());
    }
}
```

If you want to test the repository, use `@DataJpaTest`. From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html):

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead
> apply only configuration relevant to JPA tests.

```
@DataJpaTest
public class MyRepositorTest {

    @Autowired
    // This is injected by @DataJpaTest as in-memory database
    private MyRepository repo;

    @Test
    void testCount() {
        repo.save(new MyEntity("hello"));
        repo.save(new MyEntity("world"));

        assertEquals(2, repo.count());
    }
}
```

In conclusion, the suggested approach is to test the service layer mocking the repository layer with [Mockito](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) (or similar library) and to test the repository layer with `@DataJpaTest`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the `@Autowired` in service for `MyRepository`

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    
    private final MyRepository repo; // <-- this is null
    
    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    public List<String> getData() {
        return repo.findAll().stream()
                .map(MyEntity::getData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Service Test Class**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    private MyRepository repo;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;
    
    @Test
    void getData() {
        MyEntity e1 = new MyEntity("hello");
        MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity("world");
        
        Mockito.when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e1, e2));
        
        List<String> data = service.getData();
        
        assertEquals(2, data.size());
    }
}
```